# How to cope with the bug with style lookup in controls nested in FMX Frames

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe5

I have met a bug in applying of `StyleLookup` in `TTabControl` nested in FMX Frame. The appearance of the control does not accept the style if the frame with the control is nested in a `HorzScrollBox` and at form creation the position of the frame is outside the visible area of the form. In other words if the control is visible when the form is shown the control is painted with necessary style appearance otherwise  - not.

To reproduce the bug:

1. Create a new grid metropolis application.
2. Create a Frame and put a TTabControl on it. Set `Align` of the `TabControl` to `alClient`. Add, say, 4 TTabItems.
3. Open detail form, and set its width to a value > your Screen.Width (for me 2500 was enough).
4. Copy-paste any of the Columns (Layouts), say, 2 times and use the most right layout to nest a frame in it. You will see normal presentation of tabitems at designtime. Set style settings. You will get the following picture:

[image]

Done. Run the project. You will get the bug.
At runtime the appearance of TabItem is like this:

[image]

If you set the StyleLookup manually at runtime the appearance might either not change either be set to every other item (for example 1st, 3rd and not set to 2nd and 4th though you assign the same StyleLookup to all TabItems). The other interesting finding. If you have other forms containing `TabControls` with `TabItems` (nested without frames and closer to left border of the form) for example Form2, you get the following. If you show the faulty Form1 at runtime first you will see the bug, but if you close this form and show Form2 you see proper `TabControl`. Closing Form2 and showing Form1 (faulty) afterwards will give you a proper appearance of TabControl in a faulty form. 
It has something in common with the bug reported by me earlier: [Incorrect selection of items in an FMX TListbox (Grid Metropolis UI).](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31723344/5043424) It is still not fully solved.
There was also a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32058017/5043424) yesterday but it is about an exact problem with VCL Frames and the solution is not suitable for FMX.

**Appended.**

The way is to partially set the style is to set OnPainting event handler for TTabControl in the parent form unit (it does not work being set in frame unit) and write something like this:

```
procedure TPatientsScrollF.HMDiagnosisFr1TabControl2Painting(Sender: TObject;
  Canvas: TCanvas; const ARect: TRectF);
var
  i: byte;
begin
  (Sender as TTabControl).StyleLookup := 'tabcontrolstyle';
  for i := 0 to (Sender as TTabControl).TabCount-1 do
    (Sender as TTabControl).Tabs[i].StyleLookup := 'tabitemstyle';
end;
```

But than you still get a problem - the Tabs are not drawn properly - see the lower edge of inactive Tabs.

[image: The lower edge of inactive tabs is cut]

Or even like this:

[image]

**Appended 2**

I have just met the bug appearing even at design-time after placing a frame in a form and assigning style to TabItems. The TabControl looks like in fig. 3.